# No intellisense in Visual Studio 2010 Test Projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

Is there anything special about Test Projects that would cause intellisense not to work? This is my first experience with a test project.

Comment: Not that I can think of. It should work.

Comment: Which intellisense is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think I turned off the option "Auto List members" somehow. Since this is a global option, I am not sure why it effected only my test project. Perhaps because the Test project was created last, just before the option was accidentally changed. (Theorizing.)

Thanks for your replies.